# low voltage cut off for 1-cell lithium battery

Tags: voltage, low-voltage

I am designing a device running on a 1-cell lithium battery.

I am really struggling to design the low voltage cut off.

[This document](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/lt-journal/LT1389_0699_Mag.pdf) seems to be a very good solution, but those old parts can't be found anymore.

Later on, I found this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213304/tl431-low-battery-cut-off). I think it could be a good solution but this circuit draws 100uA which seems to be a lot...

Do you have any good and cheap solution for a low cut off voltage for a 1-cell lithium battery ?

If you think that using TLV431 is still a good solution, then could you help me selecting the right resistors values as I can't find what those should be in the datasheet?

If it can help, I already use an LDO 3.3V regulator: MCP1700

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seiko makes a large array of battery protection IC's. They are the industry leader for single cell battery protection. They provide not only low voltage cutoff, but also over-voltage protection, over current charge and discharge protection, too. I have no vested interest in Seiko. It is just that they are the standard solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mkeith . You're right, Seiko IC's are quite interesting. I found this one : [S-8261ABJMD-G3JT2G](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/360/S8261_E-89.pdf) which looks quite interesting.

There is an example at page 24 of the datasheet. Can I use [BSS138](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/BSS138.pdf) for the mosfet? That mosftet has a Gate Threshold Voltage  of 1.3V.

Comment: You want to look at Rds(on) and what voltage the Rds is specified at. The threshold voltage is specified at some small current (100uA or 1mA). Use a MOSFET with Rds(on) that is specified at 3V or lower (2.7V would be even better). The Rds should be small enough that it causes insignificant voltage drop at the current you are using. You could maybe say 0.1V at peak current. That is somewhat up to you.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly, I need to look at the Rds(on) in the worst case scenario. Which is 2.7v and with the maximum current that is going to go through the mosfet. Which is 500mA if charged via USB. Can you confirm that everything that I said is right? Once I have the worst case Rds(on) value, I figure out the worst case threshold voltage, right? How do I do that?

Comment: @mkeith , I don't know if you saw my last message ;)

Comment: You figure out what is the max Rds(on) you can accept. Then you find a FET with Rds(on) specified to be lower than your max at 2.7V. Don't worry about the threshold voltage directly. The threshold voltage is always lower than any voltage where Rds is specified. Most of the protection circuits I have seen use a dual FET. There is one for charge and one for discharge, because the protection circuit enables charge and discharge separately in some cases. Try to find an example circuit and study the datasheets for all the parts.

Comment: Be cautious if you buy protection boards for this purpose. Most distributors are now distributing boards with a DW01 protection IC that has a low voltage (over discharge) cutoff way too low, around 2.4v
Many of them falsely advertise a higher low cut voltage of 2.7 or 3.0 volts but then send the DW01 units.
These boards will degrade or damage your batteries. I don't know why they're doing this, but it's getting difficult to find protection boards with the correct specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linear Tech circuit is nothing more than a simple comparator circuit. If you really can't find the parts, just replace the LT1495 with another low power comparator. The LT1389 still seems to be widely available, but yet again, any old low current 1.25V reference will do.

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately, the alternatives draw quite a lot of current...

Comment: @arckin What alternatives? Comparators? If you can't find an equivalent or better part, you're not looking hard enough.